# About ideals contained in the union of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am trying to solve the following exercise: Let $R$ be a commutative ring (here a ring is assumed to always have a multiplicative identy) and consider the following property for an ideal $I$:

(1) For every set $S$ of prime ideals of $R$, i.e. $S\subseteq spec(R)$, if $I$ is contained in the union of the prime ideals in $S$ it is already contained in one of them.

Show that, if (1) holds for all prime ideals, it already holds for all ideals.

The result reminds me of prime avoidance, but I have no clue how to approach the problem. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: _the union of the prime ideals in _ Do you mean **all** prime ideals in $S$? Do your rings have identity? This is trivially true then since every ideal is contained in some maximal (hence prime) ideal.

Comment: Think it's time for a reference check on the exercise, if this is truly the wording you've been given.

Comment: I always assume rings have an identy. I will add this in the problem description. $S$ is the union of some prime ideals in $R$ not all prime ideals. So if you want $S\subseteq spec(R)$.

Comment: The exercise was given in a course I am currently taking. I think with the added information the trivial solution is discarded since I can exclude the maximal ideal from $S$. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The complement of a union of prime ideals is a multiplicative set, and an ideal which is maximal with respect to not meeting a given multiplicative set is prime

Comment: @math54321 Thanks for your help! I think I understand it now.